# On the usage of “beschenken” or “schenken” in this sentence

Tags: difference, verb, meaning-in-context, reflexive

I want to translate

> Give yourselves gifts, then [as a result of that] you love yourselves.

into German and so far I have:

> (Be)schenkt euch, dann liebt ihr euch.
>
> (Be)schenkt euch gegenseitig, dann liebt ihr euch.

I am confused about *sich schenken* and *sich beschenken,* and as to whether *gegenseitig* is necessary here.

Comment: Are you sure that the English original is with *yourselves* and not with *each other?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it short and simple - I don't think you need much of an explanation for this, if you do, please comment it - you have to use "Beschenkt euch, dann liebt ihr euch".
The "gegenseitig" makes it clear that the people you are talking are more than just one person. Just "Beschenkt euch" could be confused with you talking to just one person, meaning he just gift himself something. But I'm sure everyone would understand it without the gegenseitig.

"Schenkt euch" needs an object, such as "Schenkt euch Socken, dann liebt ihr euch".